# Is it possible to detect if a QR code is scanned with JavaScript / Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, qr-code

In my Laravel application, I am using a QR code that opens a direct WhatsApp chat when scanned. I am using the qrcode.js library to generate the QR code on the page, this is my JavaScript for generating the QR code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=+XXXXXX&text=Hello");
    </script>
```

What I want to achieve is, to display a popup saying "Successfully scanned" to the user, once the QR Code has been scanned.. Is it possible to detect when the user has scanned the QR Code? If yes? How can it be done?

Comment: You can set the URL to something that you control and use that to display the popup but this will happen when the user follows the scanned URL not when they just scan the QR code. Scanning the QR code doesn't generally broadcast anything outside the device that the QR code is scanned on unless you also control the app the code is scanned on

Comment: Yes. I agree with apokryfos. You will use another APP to scan the QR code. So it depends on whether the APP will share the event with you.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect when QR scanned. You need a websocket connection for this. When the barcode is scanned, you can give user information about the situation with socket connection.

Step 1. Listen socket connection on client with javascript. (eg. Socket.io, WebSocket)

Step 2. When barcode is scanned send success request to websocket server from qr scanner device.

Step 3. After, send information about the status from websocket server to the current websocket listening client.

You can review the examples below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

https://github.com/websockets/ws

https://socket.io/